# The opposite of "one size fits all"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

Is there a neat word or phrase that summarizes the opposite of "one size fits all"? "One size does not fit all" is not an option. What am looking for is something that means "different sizes for anybody, for every occasion etc.".

Comment: There is [made to measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Made_to_measure) and [tailored](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tailored) which are both also antonyms of [off-the-rack](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-the-rack).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a couple possible opposites:

- "Made to order" — the product is customized each time to a new specification. This is the extreme opposite.
- "Available in a variety of sizes" — there are several sizes available for the given product.

Comment: For the record, I do also like "custom-fit" and "bespoke". Bespoke has made it into the American lexicon, if not broadly.

Answer (score 10):

Consider **[custom-fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custom-Fit)**

> personalized with regard to shape and size

A Britishism that is sometime heard in the US is **[bespoke](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bespoke)**

> (Of goods, especially clothing) made to order:
>   *a bespoke suit*

Comment: Bespoke is rather obscure.  Most people in the US would not figure it out even from contextual clues.

Answer (score 1):

**context specific**

> Implementation of software solutions are typically *context specific*. The implementation depends on the amount of data used, hardware available, the business user's priorities, the level of ability of the users etc.

Answer (score 1):

This may be venturing away from English usage and into slogans, but maybe you could write "Our Sizes Fit All"? Realistically, it might be best to specify which sizes instead of groping for a single generic word to say "various sizes," although that phrase might work.

You could call it "sized" clothing, however it's much more common to use the word in a combination: *an average-sized insect*, *an awkwardly sized package*.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider [*bespoke*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bespoke) (definition from http://www.merriam-webster.com):

> - made to fit a particular person
> - custom-made
> - dealing in or producing custom-made articles

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of idioms which cover the basic idea that everyone's needs or wants are not identical:

> Horses for courses
>
> To each his own

The adjectives/adjectival phrases *custom*, *customized*, *fitted*, *tailor-made*, *individually made*, *configurable* and *unique-fit* also exist.