# Word or phrase meaning "making it uniquely mine"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

What are words or phrases that describe choosing and/or adding features to a basic item that will transform it into a uniquely personal product.  For example, offered a basic dress with a list of options to "make it mine", such as sleeve length and style, collar design, color, length, etc.

Comment: related: [The opposite of “one size fits all”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163497/the-opposite-of-one-size-fits-all) and [tailored to someone needs VS tailor-made](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59975/tailored-to-someone-needs-vs-tailor-made)

Comment: Please [edit] this to show us how you would like to use this word in a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

For clothing, the word "[tailored](https://wordnik.com/words/personalize)" is used.  The word "[bespoke](https://wordnik.com/words/bespoke)" can also be used.

If you put your initials or name on something it is "[personalize](https://wordnik.com/words/personalize)d."

For other things, the word "[customize](https://wordnik.com/words/personalize)" is used.

Reference: The American Heritage Dictionary, 4th edition.

Comment: Tailored, personalize and customize are the words I was also going to suggest, albeit in greater detail. Worth particular note is that personalize is probably the better word than customize generally, since custom traditionally refers to habit & familiarity, whereas personal traditionally refers to things peculiar to a certain person. The function of the suffix [-ize](https://wordnik.com/words/-ize) meaning to make or practice makes more sense with personal and most other lexicons, including A.H.D. 5th, define [personalize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/personalize) as making personal too.

Comment: @Tonepoet how much greater detail can one give on this answer?